# Vertical concatenation

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, vectorization

I would ask a rather easy question, but i was unable to find an answer so far. I have a structure containing names and data lets say:

```
mystruct(1).Name = 'A' 
mystruct(1).Data = 1x100double
mystruct(2).Name = 'B'
mystruct(2).Data = 1x100double
mystruct(3).Name = 'C'
mystruct(3).Data = 1x100double
```

now i want to create an array of doubles from 'A' and 'C' with the dimension 2x100double. The only thing i could come up with is:

```
thingsiwant = [1;3]
myarray = [mystruct(thingsiwant)]
```

whoever the data ends up being 1x200 rather than 2x100. I tried a few combinations of vector dimensions but i couldn't come up with a solution and right now i went for

```
myarray = reshape([mystruct(thingsiwant)],2,100)
```

which works but does not look nice as code. Is there a nicer way to get what i want? Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try the `horzcat` function?

Comment: @Dan shouldn't it be `vertcat` since the OP wants vertical concatenation?

Comment: @Benoit_11 correct, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

```
mystruct(1).Name = 'A';
mystruct(1).Data = 1:100;
mystruct(2).Name = 'B';
mystruct(2).Data = 1:100;
mystruct(3).Name = 'C';
mystruct(3).Data = 1:100;

A = vertcat(mystruct(thingsiwant).Data);
size(A)
```

output:

```
ans =

     2   100
```

Comment: thank you guys! i like the vertcat most for code clearity

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray = cat(1,mystruct(thingsiwant).Data)
```